# iTextSharp Properties using HashTable or something else?

Tags: c#, pdf, hashtable, itext

noob to C# here, using iTextSharp examples from around SO I've made a basic exe to change title, description and keywords to an existing PDF. Using MS Visual C# 2010, I don't understand all this 'Generic' change to C#, so I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' to 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
```

and

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if ((args == null) || (args.Length < 3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("args: PDFProp [fileName] [outputPath] [Title] [Description] [Keywords]");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("<Continue>");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            string filePath = args[0];
            string newFilePath = args[1];
            string title = args[2];
            string desc = "";
            string keywords = "";
            if (args.Length > 3)
                desc = args[3];
            if (args.Length > 4)
                keywords = args[4];

            Console.Write(filePath + "->" + newFilePath + " title: " + title + " description: " + desc + " keywords: " + keywords);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(newFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //   string title = pdfReader.Info["Title"] as string;           

                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fileStream);

                // The info property returns a copy of the internal HashTable
                Hashtable newInfo = pdfReader.Info;             // error 1 

                newInfo["Title"] = title;

                if (args.Length > 3)
                    newInfo["Description"] = desc;
                if (args.Length > 4)
                    newInfo["Keywords"] = keywords;

                pdfStamper.MoreInfo = newInfo;                  // error 2

                pdfReader.Close();
                pdfStamper.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the below line:

```
Dictionary<string,string> newInfo = pdfReader.Info;
```

instead of

```
Hashtable newInfo = pdfReader.Info;
```

Should fix both errors.

The reason why this is happening is because you are trying to cast from a Hashtable to a Generic Dictionary and the hashtable does not have an [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) type conversion available for this. look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yh14awz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to see the difference between a hashtable and a Dictionary.

Comment: Yours is definitely correct so I'll up-vote it. I just wanted to add that when discovering a new library with C# its sometimes easier to use `var` keyword when getting calling methods and accessing properties. `var newInfo = pdfReader.Info;` You can definitely abuse `var` but for things like this it can be very helpful.

Comment: Chris, yeah, but for the sake of clarity I would rather use the full definition to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ahh thankyou guys, I for the life of me couldn't see where: pdfReader.Info was defined as Dictionary, where is the documentation for pdfReader.Info?

Comment: Should be with the ITextSharp documentation, but to see what public methods and return values a class contains without having the source, you can still right click go to definition

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this line

```
Hashtable newInfo = pdfReader.Info;
```

throws the error, and then also this one:

```
pdfStamper.MoreInfo = newInfo;
```

pdfStamper.MoreInfo seems to be of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary, so all you have to do is replace

```
Hashtable newInfo = pdfReader.Info;
```

by

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string> newInfo = pdfReader.Info;
```

The types must match. I can't test this, so I don't know if I've found the correct lines, but something like this will work.